# typedef solving for dll wrapper

Tags: c, dll, typedef, word-wrap, arguments

I want to write a wrap for a DLL file, in this case for python. The problem is that the argument types are not the C standard ones. They have been typedef'end to something else.

I have the header files for the DLL files... so I can manually track the original standard C type the argument type was typedef'ined to. But wanted a more systematic way to do this. I was wondering whether there is a utility that would evaluate the header files, or if you can get somewhere in the dll the types definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the tool you are looking for is [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/):

> SWIG is a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages. SWIG is used with different types of languages including common scripting languages such as Perl, PHP, Python, Tcl and Ruby. The list of supported languages also includes non-scripting languages such as C#, Common Lisp (CLISP, Allegro CL, CFFI, UFFI), Java, Lua, Modula-3, OCAML, Octave and R. Also several interpreted and compiled Scheme implementations (Guile, MzScheme, Chicken) are supported. SWIG is most commonly used to create high-level interpreted or compiled programming environments, user interfaces, and as a tool for testing and prototyping C/C++ software. SWIG can also export its parse tree in the form of XML and Lisp s-expressions. SWIG may be freely used, distributed, and modified for commercial and non-commercial use.

This does assume that you are willing to use the headers for the DLL.  If you want to work solely with the DLL, then you have more work to do.  It might provide a reflection interface that you can use to analyze the types.  Failing that, you are into a world of pain - or reverse engineering any debugging information in the DLL.

Comment: Some instructions on how to setup VC++ with swig to make the module
http://realmike.org/blog/2010/07/18/python-extensions-in-cpp-using-swig/#dll

plus in the module_wrap.c file I would set the statement
#undef _DEBUG
just before 
#include <python.h>